# going home and going to work

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

The other day I've learned that you cannot use "to" in the sentence "I am going (to) home". At the same time, you should use "to" with other place names. For example, I am going to work.

Could someone, please, explain the rule why we cannot use "to" with the word home? Are there any other words that we should use without "to"?